# Maharam Shiff’s Mnemonic indexes

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, jewish-books

The Wikipedia page (from Jewish encyclopedia) for Rabbi Meir Shiff states:

> A mnemonic index to the Bible and the Talmud by him is also extant.

Where can I find such an index?

Comment: does that statement have an attribution in the meta-wikipedia? perhaps you can contact the author there.

Comment: This statement is very strange. I went through the sources brought by the Jewish Encyclopedia (from which this Wiki article was copied) and found no mention of such a work.

Comment: It'd be nteresting to know if his writings are particularly promotive of the study of scripture and perhaps that will be indicative an inkling to the truth @Harel13

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough. However, many of the sources listed (and others I found along the way) talk about how he leaned towards writing in as a concise manner as possible. Sometimes he wrote that there's much more to discuss but he doesn't want to write so much so he's leaving things at that. On the other hand, a collection of his drashot on Tanach were printed and these are said to be the opposite of his approach to Talmud and halacha - flowery, classic drashic-style drashot.